# How do I make tkinter run whilst inside a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

here is some code ive made for a very very basic menu, with just two buttons

```
import tkinter as ui
import time as time

def mainmenu():
    menuwin = ui.Tk()
    manualbutton = ui.Button(
        text = "Manual",
        width = 25,
        height = 5,
    )
    autobutton = ui.Button(
        text = "Automatic",
        width = 25,
        height = 5,
    )
    manualbutton.pack()
    autobutton.pack()
    
    menuwin.mainloop()
    return
```

however when i run this, the tkinter ui window does not pop up, and the console window (as im using visual studio) just asks me to press any key to continue.

how do i get tkinter to run in functions so that i can create little pieces of recallable code?

Comment: Why is there a return at the end of the code? Also you might need to call the function using mainmenu()

Comment: You didn't call `mainmenu()`, so none of the code inside it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call mainmenu like this

```
mainmenu()
```